# How can i implement nested loop in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Currently i have this

```
def convert_tuple(self, listobj, fields=None):
    return [(obj.start, obj.end) for obj in listobj]
```

But i have hard coded the fields.

I want to have fields as another list like

```
def convert_tuple(self, listobj, fields=['start', 'end', 'user']):
    return [(obj.field) for obj in listobj for field in fields]
```

How can i implement that

Expected output

```
[('2am', '5am', 'john'), ('3am', '5am', 'john1'), ('3am', '5am', 'john2') ]
```

where 2am is start , 5am is end , john is username

Comment: Example input with desired output would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage python builtin [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) along with nested list comprehension to achieve what you are envisaging.

```
def convert_tuple(self, listobj, fields=['start', 'end', 'user']):
    return [(getattr(obj, field) for  field in fields)
            for obj in listobj]
```

It is worth noting that your comprehension is rather a cartesian product rather than a nested comprehension

Comment: How can i display it properly currently i get `[genexpres, genexpression]` , i want to  expand it